# Python Queue - Share Queue between multiple instances of same class

Tags: python, class, multiprocessing, queue, instance

I am declaring queue as class level attribute and want it to accessed by all instances of class.
Please check code below
In below code tObj1 and tObj2 are two objects of test class, I want them to share eq. But its not happening.

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process


class test:
    eq = Queue()

    def producer(self):
        test.eq.put(1)
        print("producer test.eq.empty()" + str(test.eq.empty()))
        print("producer Queue Size-:" + str(test.eq.qsize()))

    def consumer(self):
        print("consumer test.eq.empty()" + str(test.eq.empty()))
        print("consumer Queue Size-:" + str(test.eq.qsize()))
        if not test.eq.empty():
            data_to_ret = test.eq.get(block=False)
            print("Data" + str(data_to_ret))


class Main:

    def main(self):
        if __name__ == '__main__':
            p1 = Process(target=self.call_producer, args=(10,))
            p2 = Process(target=self.call_consumer, args=(10,))
            p1.start()
            p2.start()
            p1.join()
            p2.join()

    def call_producer(self, num):
        tObj1 = test()
        while 1:
            tObj1.producer()
            time.sleep(10)

    def call_consumer(self, num):
        tObj2 = test()
        while 1:
            tObj2.consumer()
            time.sleep(10)


m = Main()
m.main()
```

I expect same queue to be accessed from both consumer and producer.
Below is  the output

```
producer test.eq.empty()False
producer Queue Size-:1
consumer test.eq.empty()True
consumer Queue Size-:0
producer test.eq.empty()False
producer Queue Size-:2
consumer test.eq.empty()True
consumer Queue Size-:0
```

Comment: The class attribute `test.eq` is redefined every time you start another process (since it's defined at the top-level module). This means, that every process will have a different version of `test.eq` and will not see items put on another process's `test.eq`. So, the simplest fix here is to explicitly pass the queue as an argument when starting the functions `call_producer` and `call_consumer`

Comment: Yes got the solution passing queue as argument in call_producer and call_consumer, resolved it

Comment: As an aside, you should put the `if __name__ == '__main__':` test around the statements `m = main(); m.main()`.